# Given a child (subset of parent) numpy array, find indices of that on parent array?

Tags: numpy, indices, numpy-slicing

I have two arrays

```
Parent array (A) = [2,1,2,1,4,4,3]

child array (B) = [1,2,3,4] ( it is actually uniq of A)
```

I want to find indicies in A for elements of B using numpy

In this case, it is

```
[1,3,0,2,6,4,5]
```

It would be great if I have it in dict like this

```
{1: [1,3], 2: [0,2], 3:[6], 4: [4,5] }
```

Comment: did you explore `unique` parameters?

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loops doesn't look to bad here:

```
out_dict = {}
for a in enumerate(A):
    if a in out_dict:
        out_dict.append(i)
    else:
        out_dict[a] = [i]
```

Comment: I prefer using NumPy. A is usually large

Comment: @ProtonBoss numpy doesn't really help if you want a dictionary output.

Comment: @ProtonBoss on the other note, your first request is `np.argsort(A)`.